# The site magic links should add .SE to their titles

Tags: discussion, magic-links

We use magic links to get a text-ready link to the SE sites. For example the magic link

`[cryptography.se]` provides a link to [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

When we say;

- this question better be asked on [cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

it hides a detail about the link; cryptography of where.

If we used

- this question better be asked on [cryptography.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)

This indicates that cryptography.SE is a Stack Exchange site and this is more indicative than the current version.

Shouldn't we update the magic text?

Comment: This would look awkward for all sites that are not one word, because you'd end up with something like "English Language & Usage.SE" as the text of the link. What is wrong with using whatever wording fits the context of how it is being used? Those magic links exist to provide a quick link to the site, not to force specific wording that may not be desired.

Comment: Is this discussion only applies to magic links that end with `.SE`? Otherwise, `[so]`, `[su]`, and `[sf]` will be more confusing, [so].SE? [su].SE? [sf].SE?

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. yes, I did not consider them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The advantage of the current implementation is that you're free to choose your own version:

- This question is better asked on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).SE
- This question is better asked on [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange
- This question is better asked on our sister site [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)
- This question would receive better answers from our [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) experts

.SE in itself can be confusing as well, especially if you only know Stack *Overflow* (not unlikely as a new user) and/or live in Sweden, which has the `.se` Top Level Domain.

Comment: I try to avoid using ".SE" because of the TLD. You get the same effect by removing the period: "Cryptography SE".